# Recognize current hashtag or tag in edittext

Tags: android, mysql, tags, android-edittext, hashtag

I have and EditText where I can write words, hashtag and tags. I recognize all tags or hashtags with Linkify and I can get all them when I press a button with this method:

```
            String text = editText.getText().toString();
            String[] words = text.split(" ");
            List<String> hashtags = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();

            for ( String word : words) {
                if (word.substring(0, 1).equals("#")) {
                    Log.i("HASHTAG", word);
                    hashtags.add(word);
                }
                if (word.substring(0, 1).equals("@")) {
                    Log.i("TAG", word);
                    tags.add(word);
                }
            }
```

Now I'd like to take the tag when I'm writing and do a request to my database for suggesting to the user some word. How I can take the part of hashtag that I insert and then search it?

For example if I write: "I think that @ta"
i want to take "ta" and search it in my database and then I will populate my listview with: "tank" "take" "taste"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a [TextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) like this:

```java
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
            String text = s.toString()
            if (text.lastIndexOf("@") > text.lastIndexOf(" ")){
                String tag = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf("@"), text.length());
                // search for tag...
            }
        }
    });
```